# Does North Korea require entry visas for its own citizens?

Tags: law, north-korea

According to this article, it does: https://www.nknews.org/2014/12/north-koreas-passports-and-how-they-use-them/

> ... both citizens and foreigners need both an entry and an exit visa. Usually they are issued as one “exit and entry,” but there are other cases as well.

I have not been able to verify this claim.

Comment: I don't understand. If citizens need a "visa" then it's not a visa, but something else.

Comment: it's permit I guess

Comment: It is worth noting North Korea citizens aren't normally allowed to exit the country in the first place. So, I wonder what exceptions might exist to allow them to exit the country?

Comment: @GeorgeChalhoub, some N.Koreans work abroad, https://news.vice.com/article/cash-for-kim-how-north-koreans-are-working-themselves-to-death-in-europe

Comment: That link is behind a subscription

Comment: @JanDoggen try googling for the quoted text and then clicking the lin; that should let you read the article

Comment: Not in my Google bubble.

Comment: @fredsbend USSR had an "exit visa", called exactly like that. So wording is not surprising here. Also Oxford dictionary includes this meaning https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/visa